# Prove $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x = 4$

Tags: calculus

Show that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x = 4$

So my textbook has a proof for this and this is their scratch work:

$\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists\delta>0$ s.t $\forall x$ $0<|x-4|<\delta \implies |\sqrt{x}-2|<\epsilon$

Working backwards:

$$|\sqrt{x}-2|<\epsilon \iff \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+2}|x-4| < \epsilon$$

then they stated that 'let us assume that $\delta\le4$'

$$|x-4|<\delta \implies |x-4|<4 ...$$

My question is why did they assume that $\delta\le4$ (there was no explaintion in the text) instead of the normal cases when you assume that $\delta\le1$?

Comment: I've corrected a typo; check to make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of choosing an upper bound is to deal with the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + 2}$ term; we want to ensure that this term doesn't get too big.

Since it can't possibly be bigger than $\frac{1}{2}$, all we really need to worry about is to ensure that $x > 0$, so that the function is actually defined.

Insisting that $\delta \leq 4$ works for this purpose, but we could have chosen any smaller value as well. (it's *always* okay to make $\delta$ smaller than it 'needs' to be)

For other dealing with sorts of terms, usually *any* choice of $\delta$ is fine. Sometimes there are exceptions: e.g. if the extra term to deal with was $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} - 1}$, then insisting on $x > 1$ isn't good enough, because this term can become arbitrarily large. However, insisting that $x > 1.1$ is fine (which can be achieved by insisting $\delta \leq 2.9$).

Answer (score 0):

If $\delta \gt 4$ then there are negative $x$ which satisfy $|x-4|\lt \delta$ but for which there is not real $\sqrt{x}$.

Using "let us assume $\delta \le 1$" would in fact have worked here, but would not have worked if the original question had been "Prove $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x=\frac12$."   So it is reasonable to assume an upper bound for $\delta$ which relates to the actual question.